# USB via MAX3421

Tags: usb, pi-zero-w, spi

I am trying to get an additional USB port working by using the MAX3421 chip over SPI on a Raspberry Pi Zero W running raspbian.
I have successfully installed the driver as a kernel module. The chip gets recognized and provides a second USB Bus. When I plug in a device, most show up in lsusb, some don't. But all have in common that they're unuseable. Meaning: Thumb drives don't provide a /dev/ entry, ethernet adapters don't provide a network adapter etc.

Dmesg gives me messages like this for a thumb drive:

```
[ 70.129597] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

[ 74.469457] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

[ 78.809434] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

[ 83.149378] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

[ 83.152772] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2

[ 87.509394] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?

[ 91.844564] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

If I try a USB-to-ethernet adapter I get this:

```
[ 44.569600] asix 2-1:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Failed to read reg index 0x0000: -110

[ 44.569697] asix: probe of 2-1:1.0 failed with error -110

[ 44.569912] usbcore: registered new interface driver asix
```

All the devices I've tried work when plugged into the Raspberry's built-in USB port.

Things I've tried:

- Used a self-powered USB hub to rule out power supply issues. Same result, devices show up in lsusb, but don't do anything after that.
- Applied a pull-up resistor to the IRQ pin to make sure the Raspberry doesn't recieve unintendet interrupt signals. No changes.
- Tried to reset the USB port at runtime using ioctrl in a c script. Also, no changes.
- Extensive search about UBS error code -110, but there's nothing applicable to my case.

I know this is very specific, but I would be grateful for any clues about where to look for this error.

Thanks in advance!